# Observing REST API requests from 3rd party

Tags: event-observer, shipping, soap, rest-api

I would like to know if there are any API events that are fired when a third party API sends a request to Magento?

For example, if a 3rd party makes a call to `salesOrderShipmentCreate()` method `app/code/core/Mage/Sales/etc/wsdl.xml` would my observer still fire if it were listening for `sales_order_shipment_save_after` ?

I would appreciate if anyone knows if this approach would still work, if not which event should I listen for when API calls made to Magento from a third party...